# Can I use REST-API on plain permalink format?

Tags: permalinks, rest-api

Recently all of my REST-API requests suddenly turned to return a 404 error, Every request (no matter custom endpoint or built-in).

Then I figured it's because of permalink's structure. `/wp-json/` is not accessible under plain permalink, since there is simply no redirect rule available at the moment.

Is it possible to use the REST endpoints in this situation? Both custom and built-in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can. Just add the `rest_route` query parameter.

So

https://wordpress.org/wp-json/

would become

https://wordpress.org/?rest_route=/

Or `https://wordpress.org/wp-json/wp/v2/` would become `https://wordpress.org/?rest_route=/wp/v2` to give you a more complete example.

So you're wondering how to decide which one to use? Worry no more, there's a function for that: [`get_rest_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/)

Another option is the fact that by default there is a `<link>` in the header that gives you the API root.

```
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='https://wordpress.org/wp-json/' />
```

So in case you need to figure that out from client side JS just use something along the lines of

```
document.querySelector('link[rel="https://api.w.org/"]').getAttribute('href');
```

---

So basically you shouldn't take the `wp-json` part as given (and hardcode it) but always build it dynamically either using `get_rest_url()` or the JS approach mentioned above.

Comment: So, if I want to use it in plain, it would be something like `https://wordpress.org/?rest_route=SOMEPATH&value1=X&value2=Y`? This means I need to have a conditional to detect the permalink structure and change the REST route based on that?

Comment: Well maybe not a conditional but you need to build it dynamically. See edits above.

Comment: how would you use this route with jsonp? I tried `/?rest_route=/?_jsonp=callBackfn` but get a 404 status.

Comment: @redshift Usually please open a separate question for things like these. In your case you should read up on query string delimiters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure You'd need to write it like this `/?rest_route=/&_jsonp=callBackfn`

Comment: client side check is brilliant. makes things much easier than having to localize a script.

Answer (score 1):

You could add one rewrite on your web server.

E.g for nginx

```
location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
    rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rest_route` query parameter is the `Ugly` (Wordpress's choice of words not mine) style of Permalink.  You can change the permilink style to `Post name` as illustrated in the screen shot below and the `wp-json` route should beomce accessable in the URL. It is possible that other of these permilink styles will work, but `Post name` worked for me and I didn't explore beyond that

[image: Picture illustrating button clicks required to change settings]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I make a dynamic rest URL in PHP. Then just add on your parameters.

```
$rest_url = get_rest_url();
$delimiter = str_contains($rest_url, '/wp-json/') ? '?' : '&';
$api_url = $rest_url . 'my-api/v1/route' . $delimiter;
```

`$delimiter` dynamically changes depending on `$rest_url`

Old question, but I think it will benefit from a more complete single answer. I was also hardcoding in "/wp-json/", and found this in my search for a solution to both plain and pretty permalink structures.